# Dynamically create table from Ajax response

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have a Flask app that returns JSON response based on an AJAX call. I created a table from this response, given I already know the column names:

```
#Flask App
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def process():
    # ... queries database and returns value in list of dicts
    response = jsonify(db_result_dict)
    return response


//js
response = $.parseJSON(response);
$(function () {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.id),
        $('<td>').text(item.location),
        $('<td>').text(item.category)).appendTo('#my_table');       
    });
});


<!--html-->
<table id="my_table">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>location</th>
        <th>category</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Without Ajax, I used to do something like this with Jinja:

```
#Flask app
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def process():
        # ... queries database and returns value in list of dicts
        # ... get list of keys    
        return render_template('page.html', columns=list_of_keys, data=db_result_dict)


    <!--page.html-->
    <table id="my_table">
       <thead>
          {% for col in columns %}
          <td> {{ col }} </td>
          {% endfor %}
       </thead>
       {% for row in data %}
       <tr>
          {% for col in columns %}
          <td> {{row[col] }} </td>
          {% endfor %}
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

How can I dynamically create table in a similar way from Ajax, assuming I do not know the column names beforehand?

Comment: Why don't you get your Ajax view to use the Jinja tempate and return rendered HTML?

Comment: For one, Ajax doesnt want dict and list, except Json. Could you please point me to an example of how I can approach this json with Jinja ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

Simply, I made the table in `page.html` into an external html file and added the required jinja template to it. Then in my Flask app I returned the render_template response to the jquery ( which contained the HTML I wanted to append ). And then simply append the HTML from the response to the required div to be updated